# Figuring out the scope of variables to make a simple function work correctly

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

The following VBA routine isn't working and I can't figure out why...

I've tried setting a set of public variables at the top to make the variables go between functions but it's not working.

The end result of the code below should make `getthename` have the value of `cow`

```
Sub test()
    getthename = test2(test1("elephant"))
End Sub

Function test1(NewTitle As String) As String
    If NewTitle = "elephant" Then
        NewTitle = "horse"
    Else
        NewTitle = "pig"
    End If
End Function

Function test2(NewTitle As String) As String
    If NewTitle <> "horse" Then
        NewTitle = "cow"
    Else
        NewTitle = "rabbit"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't understand the changes you mentioned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have your functions actually return a value:

```
Sub test()
    getthename = test2(test1("elephant"))
End Sub

Function test1(NewTitle As String) As String
    If NewTitle = "elephant" Then
        test1 = "horse"
    Else
        test1 = "pig"
    End If
End Function

Function test2(NewTitle As String) As String
    If NewTitle <> "horse" Then
        test2 = "cow"
    Else
        test2 = "rabbit"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, I saw your post and facepalmed. I can't believe I didn't see that or understand you.